# I don't understand how to initial the linked list of the game(Snake)

Tags: c

I can't figure out how to link the tail into the head in order to initialize the list.
I understand how to link new nodes and everything after they are linked, but I can't figure out how to initialize the snake properly. It's written in C.

```
typedef struct node {
    int x;
    int y;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
} NODE;

typedef struct SNAKE {
    NODE* head;
    NODE* tail;
} SNAKE;

void initialSnaKE(SNAKE* snake) {

    snake->tail->next=snake->head;

    snake->head->next = NULL;

    snake->tail->prev = snake->tail->next;

    snake->tail->x = (ROWS / 2);

    snake->tail->y = (COLS / 2);

    snake->head->x = (ROWS / 2);

    snake->head->y = (COLS / 2);

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tricks to analyse pointer and pointer-to-pointer structures in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c)

Comment: I do not mean the immediate question and the problem described, I mean the method of understanding pointer constructs as described in the answer (admittedly mine).

Answer (score 1):

Your snake doesn't exist because you did not even allocate memory for it before making the connections within the snake body.

Remake your function to initialize the snake with the following code and it may help you:

```
snake->head = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
snake->head->prev = NULL;
snake->head->next = NULL;
// Your code to assign the coordinates of head
// But no need to initialize the tail here
// Because the snake grows its tail only when it eats food
snake->tail = NULL;
```

This much is enough for initializing the snake with the details you have provided. Connections within the snake are to be made within another function which feeds the snake. To achieve that task, you can learn about [doubly-linked lists.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/doubly-linked-list/)

Honestly, I don't think this simple game has to be this complex in code. A simple array is sufficient to implement your snake. Think about it and don't hesitate to comment your doubts regarding this simpler approach.