# Function running when it shouldn't

Tags: c

I have the following snippets of code:

```
struct TreeNode *allocate_node(char *value) {
  struct TreeNode *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
  new_node->value = value;
  new_node->sibling = NULL;
  new_node->child = NULL;
  return new_node;
}
```

```
void tree_insert(struct TreeNode *root, char **values) {

  struct TreeNode *prev = root;
  struct TreeNode *curr = prev->child;


  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (!curr) {
      prev->child = allocate_node(values[i]);

      prev = prev->child;
      curr = prev->child;
    }
  }
}
```

```
int main(void) {
  struct TreeNode root;
  root.value = "";
  root.child = NULL;
  root.sibling = NULL;

  char *command1[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
  char *command2[] = {"e", "f", "g", "h"};

  tree_insert(&root, command1);
  tree_insert(&root, command2);

  printf("Printing current tree values: \n");
  struct TreeNode *curr = root.child;
  while (curr) {
    printf("%s ", curr->value);
    curr = curr->child;
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
Current tree values:
a b c d
```

Actual output:

```
Current tree values:
e f g h
```

After the first tree_insert is run my tree is linked like this:
(root) -> a -> b -> c -> d

But when the second tree_insert runs my old tree seems to have been replaced even though tree_insert shouldn't even run. New tree is as such:
(root) -> e -> f -> g -> h

Since in the second tree_insert curr is no longer NULL, how come it's still running and overwriting my tree? I'm pretty new to C so I might be missing something really obvious

edit:
TreeNode is defined as such:

```
struct TreeNode {
    char *value;
  struct TreeNode *sibling;
  struct TreeNode *child;
};
```

Comment: C or C++? And how is TreeNode defined?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I edited the new info in. It's C

Comment: You should read the warnings from the compiler. `char *command1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};` is very iffy

Comment: Ugh sorry I edited again.

Comment: Also, you say how the linked list look like. How do you know? I don't see any  printouts in your code.

Comment: You should create a [mre] and state excpected and actual behavior.

Comment: I tested with:
 struct TreeNode *curr = root.child;
        while (curr) {
          printf("%s\n", curr->value);
          curr = curr->child;
        }

Comment: Edit your main function with minimal printouts to show the problem. Tell us what it prints. Tell us what you want it to print.

Comment: This might help, though I do not propose it as duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858

Comment: I checked it now on my computer and it was 'a->b->c->d' after both 'tree_insert' calls.

Comment: I added the expected and actual print results to the main function

Comment: @Jesse you need to provide a [MCVE]. We don't need snippets of code, we need code that we can run.

Comment: @Jesse https://ideone.com/KqEkMV

Comment: @Jabberwocky It's enough to run it now if you add the includes

Comment: @klutt still the OP should post a [MCVE] instead of code snippets we need to stich together and guess which header files were used by the OP

Comment: Wait.. I ran the stuff I put here and it worked but my actual project isn't. I must be missing something

Comment: So sorry for the confusion and wasting your time let me see if I can figure it out

Comment: @Jesse Happy to help buddy. And the best soln is when the OP finds the bug and fixes it himself/herself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_node->value = value;
```

This line leads me to believe that you are storing the pointer `value` in the structure.

The problem here is that the pointer is stored in the struct. This pointer points to some other location, usually in the stack. When this variable is changed, the data in the structure also changes.

You can store the data in the structure in the form of an array or you can use dynamic memory allocation to store the data.

For Dynamic memory allocation, the function `allocate_node` is changed as below.

```
struct TreeNode *allocate_node(char *value) {
  struct TreeNode *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
  int len = strlen(value);
  new_node->value = malloc(len +1);
  strcpy(new_node->value, value);
  new_node->sibling = NULL;
  new_node->child = NULL;
  return new_node;
}
```

To store in an array, you need to know the maximum length of `value` in advance. In this case the following changes are required.

```
struct TreeNode {
  char value[MAXLEN + 1];
  struct TreeNode *sibling;
  struct TreeNode *child;
};

struct TreeNode *allocate_node(char *value) {
  struct TreeNode *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
  strcpy(new_node->value,value);
  new_node->sibling = NULL;
  new_node->child = NULL;
  return new_node;
}
```

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: You can replace the `malloc` and `strcpy` with `new_node->value = strdup(value);`

Comment: @Rishikesh Raje Still getting output as Current tree values:
a b c d.  https://ideone.com/AKTaxa

Comment: Even if he uses the pointer in his struct this does not cause his problem (but it should be at least `const char*` I guess). But his posted code does what he expects anyway, so he made some other mistake we cant figure out