# why this code to insert a node at the tail of a linked list caused segmentation error

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, clang

I am trying to implement linkedlist function to add node at the end of the list but it triggers segmentation error almost in every line.

SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int Data) {

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* Node;
Node = malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));

SinglyLinkedListNode* current; 
current = head;


Node->data = Data;
Node->next = NULL;

if( head->next == NULL)     /* 0 element llist*/
{
    head = Node;
}
else
{
    //current = head;
    /*
            while(current->next != NULL) 
    */
    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }  // exit when current->next = lastNode->next = NULL
    current->next = Node;

}
```

Comment: Hint: think carefully about your "0 element list" case.  In particular, assigning to `head` doesn't actually do anything... remember that parameters in C are passed by value.

Comment: You can use a debugger or a tool like valgrind or address sanitizer to debug segfaults.

Comment: This migth help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858

Comment: Can you please show your complete program?  I suspect the problem has to do partly with the state of the list when this function is called.

Comment: please post a [mcve] that includes which header files are included, the definition of the struct `SinglyLinkedListNode` and other critical, missing details, including the full function that contains the posted code fragement

Comment: what is the contents of `head` when this function is called?

Answer (score 0):

This can cause seg fault:

```
while(current->next != NULL)  /* if current is NULL 
dereferencing it will cause segfault. */
```