# what is wrong with this flushing function for hash table?

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

I have a weird problem with flushing the entire hash-table.
Data structures are as below:

```
typedef struct data_entry_{
    char data[32];
    struct data_entry_ *next;
}data_entry_t;

typedef struct table_entry_{
    char hash[32];
    struct data_entry_ *next_data;
    struct table_entry_ *next_hash;
}table_entry_t;

typedef struct table_{
    table_entry_t *next;
}table_t;
```

In main function, I initialize the table with below function

```
table_t *init(){
    table_t *table = calloc(1, sizeof(table_t));
    table_entry_t *node = calloc(1, sizeof(table_entry_t));
    node->next_hash = NULL;
    node->next_data = NULL;
    strcpy(node->hash, "NULL"); 
    table->next = node;
    return table;
}
```

Add data to the table with below function:

```
int add(table_t *table, char *data){
    table_entry_t *head = table->next;
    table_entry_t *prev;
    char hash[32];
    hash_function(data, hash);

    if(!strcmp(head->hash, "NULL")){ 
        data_entry_t *item = calloc(1, sizeof(data_entry_t));
        strcpy(item->data, data);
        item->next = NULL;
        strcpy(head->hash, hash);
        head->next_data = item;
        head->next_hash = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    while(head){
        if(!strcmp(head->hash, hash)){
            data_entry_t *temp = head->next_data;
            data_entry_t *previous;
            while(temp){
                if(!strcmp(temp->data, data)){
                    printf("data exists\n");
                    return 0;
                }
                previous = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            data_entry_t *item = calloc(1, sizeof(data_entry_t));
            strcpy(item->data, data);
            item->next = NULL;
            previous->next = item;
            return 0;
        }
        prev = head;
        head = head->next_hash;
    }

    table_entry_t *pack = calloc(1, sizeof(table_entry_t));
    data_entry_t *item = calloc(1, sizeof(data_entry_t));
    strcpy(pack->hash, hash);
    strcpy(item->data, data);
    item->next = NULL;
    pack->next_data = item;
    prev->next_hash = pack;
    return 0;
}
```

And the problem is with this function:

```
int flush(table_t *table){
    table_entry_t *head = table->next;
    table_entry_t *temp;
    data_entry_t *current, *previous; 
    if(head->next_data == NULL){
        printf("table is empty\n");
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(head->hash, "NULL");
    while(head){
        current = head->next_data;
        while(current){
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
            free(previous);
        }
        temp = head;
        head = head->next_hash;
        free(temp);
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

after calling flush, when I wanna show the table, I expect to see "table is empty" but apparently this function does not free any nodes. I really appreciate if anyone help me.

Comment: What value do you expect to see in a pointer which you just freed? Hint, it is not NULL.

Comment: I should see NULL value

Comment: Nope. Read docu on free().

Comment: free() returns void. 
What should I do to make the node NULL?

Comment: Problem 1. All those pointers (temp,head, current, previous) they don't free'd up if you have an early return.

Answer (score 1):

You expect that a pointer which got freed gets the value NULL.
That however is impossible, because `free()` only receives the value inside the pointer, not the address, i.e. not pointer to the pointer.

Your code assumes that a freed pointer is NULL here:

```
if(head->next_data == NULL){
```

That however will only be the case if you write the NULL value to the pointer.

There is some code which seems similar, `strcpy(head->hash, "NULL");`, but I trust that you do not expect that to write the non-string value NULL to the pointer.

You can make sure that all pointer which you free afterwards contain NULL,  by writing it yourself. Near this `free(previous);`. It is however necessary to write NULl to the actual pointer in the linked list - and not e.g. to the variable `previous`. You can use the copy of the pointer stored in that variable to free, but not for overwriting the original.

Comment: Also worth reading when handling pointer constructs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858