# Unable to delete first element from circular linked list in c

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, circular-list

Suppose there are 3 elements(10 20 30) in the list. Now upon deleting element in the first deletes 10. Now only 20 & 30 are left. Again if I delete first element, so 20 gets deleted from the list. But now if I try to delete the lone element,i.e. 30, from the list it doesn't happen.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} list;
list *start = NULL;
list *create(list *);
list *display(list *);
list *delete_beg(list *);
int main() {
  int n;

  printf("1: Create list\n");
  printf("2: Display\n");
  printf("3: Delete first element\n");
  for (;;) {
    printf("Enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    switch (n) {
    case 1:
      start = create(start);
      printf("\nList created successfully\n");
      break;
    case 2:
      start = display(start);
      break;
    case 3:
      start = delete_beg(start);
      break;
    default:
      printf("Wrong input!!!");
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}
list *create(list *start) {
  list *new_node, *ptr;
  int num;
  printf("Enter data: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  new_node = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  new_node->data = num;
  if (start == NULL) {
    start = new_node;
    new_node->next = start;
  } else {
    ptr = start;
    while (ptr->next != start) {
      ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = start;
  }
  return start;
}
list *display(list *start) {
  list *ptr;
  if (start == NULL) {
    printf("Empty list");
    return start;
  } else {
    ptr = start;
    while (ptr->next != start) {
      printf("%d\n", ptr->data);
      ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("%d\n", ptr->data);
  }
  return start;
}
list *delete_beg(list *start) {
  list *ptr;
  if (start == NULL) {
    printf("Empty list!!!");
    return start;
  } else {
    ptr = start;
    while (ptr->next != start)
      ptr = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = start->next;
    free(start);
    start = ptr->next;
    return start;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this method for analysing your pointers. Pay special attention to which pointers all point to the element you want to delete. Especially in case of the first one there are more than you think. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858

Comment: A circular list with one element ? I guess that element's "next" points to itself. Sounds like a special case you need to handle!

Comment: Yes, when there's only one element left in the list, it points to itself. Now this is where am stuck because am unable to solve this.

Comment: @Umang testing if a pointer in a struct points to that same struct should'nt be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `delete_beg` the pointer start is never set to NULL when the list contains only one node that will be deleted.

The function can be defined the following way

```
list *delete_beg(list *start) {
  if (start == NULL) {
    printf("Empty list!!!");
    return start;
  } else {
    List *current = start;
    List *ptr = start;

    while (ptr->next != start)
      ptr = ptr->next;

    if ( ptr->next == ptr ) 
    {
        start = NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
       start = start->next;
       ptr->next = start;
    }

    free( current );

    return start;
  }
```

Comment: @Umang Then close the question selection teh answer as the best answer.