# Stack Implementation in C inserting a string

Tags: c, stack

I'm having issues with inserting a string into the stack, for some reason when I insert a string into the stack I get a random character instead of it.

I allocated space of the string so I believe this should be functioning correctly.
main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Stack structure definition */
typedef char stackitem;

struct stack {
    stackitem  d;
    struct stack *next;
};

typedef  struct stack ELEMENT;
typedef  ELEMENT   *POINTER;


void push(POINTER *Top, stackitem a)
/* Put item a into the top of the stack */
{
    POINTER temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
    temp->d = a;
    temp->next = *Top;
    *Top = temp;
    printf("Insert element %c\n", temp->d);
}

void pop(POINTER *Top)
/* Remove the top item */
{
    POINTER Top1 = *Top;
    if (Top != NULL)
    {
        *Top = Top1->next;
        printf("Remove element %c\n", Top1->d);
        free(Top1);
    }
    else
        printf("Empty stack.\n");
}

void print_stack(POINTER Top)
/*Print the contents of the stack. Do not modify the stack in any way. */
{
    printf("Start printing the stack ...\n");
    POINTER temp = Top;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%c\n", temp->d);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}

void delete_stack(POINTER *Top)
/* Delete the stack, i.e. remove all items from the stack */
{
    printf("Start deleting the stack...\n");

    POINTER Top1 = *Top;
   while (Top != NULL)
    {
        *Top = Top1->next;
        printf("Deleting element %c\n", Top1->d);
        free(Top1);
        Top1 = *Top;
    }

}

void push_string(POINTER *Top,char *string)
/* Push a string of characters into a stack. */
{
    printf("Start inserting the string ...\n");

    POINTER temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(string));
    temp->d = ( char * )malloc( ( strlen( string ) + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );
    temp->next = *Top;
    *Top = temp;
    printf("Insert element %c\n", temp->d);
}

main()
{

    POINTER top;
    top= (POINTER) NULL;
    stackitem A='A';
    stackitem B='B';
    char *C="12345";
    //printf("C is %s\n", C);
    push(&top,A);
    push(&top,B);
    print_stack(top);
//    pop(&top);
//    pop(&top);
//  print_stack(top);
    push_string(&top,C);
    print_stack(top);
    delete_stack(&top);
    print_stack(top);

}
```

If I try to insert a string I get a single random character instead of the entire string in the stack.

Comment: Try this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858

Comment: You never change `Top1` inside your delete loop.  So after the first iteration, it's pointing to a node you've already deleted.  After that it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you can't place a string in a single char .Here this `char *C="12345";` is a string ,but `stackitem  d;` is `char d` , so in `void push(POINTER *Top, stackitem a)` this `temp->d = a;` is invalid for a complete string also in`void push_string(POINTER *Top,char *string)` you can't store a string in single char. you should send string char by char like below.make up your mind if you want a single char or an array of chars,in your struct ,then write your functions based on that.

in your `push_string` function `tmep` is `POINTER` so you shouldn't allocate memory for it as a string.also you only allocate memory for `temp->d` you are not copying data in it.

in below function I send a char to `push_stirng`(which is not needed you could use `push` only , but call it like below in `main`):

```
void push_string(POINTER* Top, char string)
/* Push a string of characters into a stack. */
{
    printf("Start inserting the string ...\n");

    POINTER temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(POINTER));
    temp->d = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    temp->d = string;
    temp->next = *Top;
    *Top = temp;
    printf("Insert element %c\n", temp->d);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; C[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        push_string(&top, C[i]);
        //also if you want '\0' too after loop you can use this char t='\0';push_string(&top, t);
    }
```

also in delete stack change while condition to `while (Top1 != NULL)`.