# making a copy of a single linked liked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So what im trying to do is copying a linked list that, i made and to do so i know i need to transverse the list.

The problem is if i make a 1st copy it works but if i make a copy of the copy or another copy it gives segmentation fault and i dont understand why.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node { 
    int v; 
    struct Node* next; 
}link;

link* insert(link* head,int data)
{
    link* x;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        link *new = (link*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        new->v = data;
        new->next = NULL;
        return new;
    }
    for(x = head; x->next != NULL; x = x->next);
        link *new = (link*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        new->v = data;
        new->next = NULL;
        x->next = new;
        return head;
}

void print_lst(link* head)
{
    link* t;
    for (t = head; t != NULL; t = t->next)
        printf("* %d\n",t->v);
}

link* copy_lst(const link* head)
{
    const link* x;
    link *copy; 
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    for(x = head; x->next != NULL; x = x->next)
    {
        copy->v = x->v;
        copy->next = x->next;
    }
    return copy;
}

int main()
{
    link *head = NULL;
    head = insert(head,5);
    head = insert(head,6);
    link *head2 = NULL;
    head2 = copy_lst(head);
    print_lst(head2);
    link *head3 = copy_lst(head2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tricks to analyse pointer and pointer-to-pointer structures in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c)

Comment: Otherwise https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `copy` in `copy_list` is used uninitialized. There might be other errors, but fix this first.

Comment: i just fixed it was the node i was copying it was unitialized