# how can i delete node in binary search tree in c++ and dev c++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, dev-c++

i tried to delete node that i choose one. my deletion code couldn't work. where is my fault? there is a header file and a source file. they are connected together but i don't know my code is couldn't work ?

```
node *IkiliAgac::sil(node *kok,int no){
if(kok==NULL)
return kok;
if(kok->no>no)
{
    kok->sol=sil(kok->sol,no);
    return kok;
}
else if(kok->no<no){
    kok->sag=sil(kok->sag,no);
    return kok;
}
if(kok->sol==NULL)
{
    node* temp=kok->sag;
    delete kok;
    return temp;
}
else if(kok->sag==NULL)
{
    node* temp=kok->sol;
    delete kok;
    return temp;
}
else {
    node* succparent=kok;
    node* succ=kok->sag;
    while(succ->sol!=NULL)
    {
        succparent=succ;
        succ=succ->sol;
    }
    if (succparent!=kok)
    succparent->sol=succ->sag;
    else
    succparent->sol=succ->sag;
    kok->no=succ->no;
    delete succ;
    return kok;
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tricks to analyse pointer and pointer-to-pointer structures in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c)

Comment: `if(kok->sol=NULL)` This is an assignment, not a comparison. You are corrupting your tree.

Comment: again it doesn't work :( @IgorTandetnik

Comment: You check `if (succparent!=kok)`, but then do the exact same thing, `succparent->sol=succ->sag;`, regardless of whether the condition is true or false. Did you mean to do different things in these two cases?

Comment: No actually. This topic is little bit confuse.@IgorTandetnik