# Function delete all nodes of a given value in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, pass-by-value, function-definition

Funktion (deleteall) takes a linked list and a value and delete all the nodes that hold that value, and then return the list after changing.

```
 Pointer deleteall(Pointer l, int v)
{
  
  Pointer temp;

  while(l != NULL)
  {
    if(l->val == v) {
      temp = l;
      l = temp ->next;
      free(temp);
      
    }
    if(l == NULL) return l;
    else l = l->next;
  }
  return l;
}
```

There is no error showing, the compiler finish and nothing is showing, I think the program goes in an endless loop.

Comment: `return l;` but you modified `l`. Remember `l` at the start, and return that.

Comment: when you `free` a node you also need to "fill" the gap, that is link the previous node with the next one

Comment: the logic is very weird. "If this node has the right value, then skip the next one regardless?" Probably not what you meant to do.

Comment: This sort of problem are perfect for debuggers. Try to use `gdb`, it will allow you to execute this function line-by-line, so you can see where the behavior is wrong

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858 It should help you see all the issues mentioned in the comments. I am tempted to propose that as a duplicate...

Comment: @TSG If you know a debugger which can visualise the pointers issues here better than pen and paper, then I want to know which one that is. It is not gdb.

Comment: Show the full program including how this is called, otherwise it's not useful to speculate over.

Answer (score 0):

Your function always returns a null-pointer.

When the pointer to the head node is not passed by reference to the function as in your function definition then the function must return the pointer to the head node.

It can look the following way

```
Pointer deleteall(Pointer l, int v)
{
    while ( l && l->val == v )
    {
        Pointer temp = l;
        l = l->next;
        free( temp );
    }

    if ( l )
    {
        for ( Pointer current = l; current->next != NULL; )
        {
            if ( current->next->val == v )
            {
                Pointer temp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                free( temp );
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }

    return l;
}
```

If in main the pointer to the head node is also named like `l` then the function shall be called like

```
l = deleteall( l, v );
```

A more simple function definition can look when the pointer to the head node is passed by reference. For example

```
void deleteall(Pointer *l, int v)
{
    while ( *l != NULL )
    {
        if ( ( *l )->val == v )
        {
            Pointer temp = *l;
            *l = ( *l )->next;
            free( temp );
        }
        else
        {
            l = &( *l )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

And in main the function can be called like

```
deleteall( &l, v );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need to return a pointer. You just to need to pass the head of the list as argument. Then create a temporary pointer which is initialized to where the head points to, and from that point you can work on
2. When you find a node with the val that needs to be removed, MAKE SURE you connect the node previous and next of the node-to-be-free. Thus, the linked list, remains linked

Hereby I put a sample solution, assuming that the list a) The head is not the same val as the one which needs to released and b) The last node points-to-NULL. We keep 2 temporary pointers, pointing to a)Node and b)Node->next. We always check the Node->next, and if it is one-to-be-released, we connect the list without it, and then we release it.

```
void deleteall(Pointer l, int v)
{
  
  Pointer temp, temp2;
  temp2 = l;
  temp = temp2->next;

  while(temp != NULL)
  {
    if(temp->val == v) {
      temp2->next = temp->next;
      free(temp);
      temp = temp2->next

    } else
    {
      temp2 = temp;
      temp = temp->next;
    if(temp == NULL)
      break;

  return;}
```

This solution can be optimized, but it helps me personally, especially if I draw a diagram with pointers and nodes.

Comment: Your function can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Please go on and correct me with details, you are welcome :)

Comment: _'You do not need to return a pointer.'_ Depending on the required interface, the function may be given a 'head' pointer and required to return a 'head' pointer (which may differ, if the first item gets deleted).

Comment: This solution can also be beautified by consistent indentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a short implementation. It utilizes a `prev` pointer which points to previous pointer, pointing to a current element. This way we can easily check whether the current element exists (the list isn't exhausted) and advance the pointer along the list or hold on the current position if the current elements gets deleted an the next one replaces it.

```
Pointer deleteall(Pointer l, int v)
{
    Pointer* prev = &l;

    while (*prev != NULL)        // any items after the previous one?
    {
        Pointer curr = *prev;    // yes - so this is our current item
        if (curr->val == v)
        {
            *prev = curr->next;  // link next item to prev
            free(curr);
        }
        else
            prev = & curr->next; // step forward on the list
    }
    return l;                    // a new head of the list
}
```