# Delete function in linked-list

Tags: c, linked-list

Do you understand why when i call the `delete` function here the output become an infinite loop? Without that function the code works.

```
int main(){

    node *head = NULL;

    end(&head);
    begin(&head);
    begin(&head);
    end(&head);
    begin(&head);
    end(&head);
    begin(&head);
    delete(&head);
    display(head);

    return 0;
}

void delete(node **head){
    node *tmp,*prev = NULL;
    int num;
    printf("Insert the number that you want to delete: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    tmp = *head;
    if (tmp->data == num){
        *head = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
        return;
    }
    while(tmp->data!=num && tmp!=NULL){
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    if(tmp == NULL){
        return;
    }
    prev->next = tmp->next;
    free(tmp);
}
```

Those are my other function:

```
void begin(node **head){
    node *new;
    int num;
    new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new ==  NULL){
        perror("malloc");
        EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Insert number at the beginning: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    new->data  = num;
    new->next = *head;
    *head = new;
}

 void end(node **head){
    int num;
    node *tmp,*new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new == NULL){
        perror("malloc");
        EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Insert number at the end: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    new->data = num;
    tmp = *head;
    if(tmp == NULL){
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->data = num;
        tmp->next = NULL;
    }
    while(tmp->next!=NULL){
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    new->next = NULL;
    tmp->next = new;
}


void display(node *head){
    node *tmp;
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("Empty list");
    }
    else{
        while(tmp!=NULL){
            printf("%d ",tmp->data);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try this approach and report on your findings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858

Comment: I think the problem might be outside of the shown code, please provide a [mre].

Comment: Maybe not your answer but `while(tmp->data!=num && tmp!=NULL)` is a wrong condition. You must check first  `tmp!=NULL` and then `tmp->data!=num`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I fixed the prev problem ans now i add the others function, the main() part is only that

Comment: I mean the pointer to node *prev now is declared node *prev = NULL

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding (which became apparent with your now deleted non-answer). What is said was not to change the question to a new problem. Adding information for the old problem was good work. You just should add it to the question.

Comment: Your display function ignores the parameter, at least inside the `else`. No idea how that caues an infinite loop however.

Comment: Yes i see that when i posted it. Thank you for your help

Comment: See, that is why people here so unchangably insist on seeing a MRE. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i understand the problem. I forgot to add `tmp = head` in the `else{}` condition in the `display()` function

Comment: If you explain how this causes the endless loop, then this is a good and helpful answer.

Comment: No i don't know unfortunately, I'm a beginner eheh

Comment: In that case please allow me to turn my comment into an answer. Ah, forget it. You deserve the reputation for going along with my nagging.... ;-) Please understand the other answer, too. But you can accept your own answer (or the other one), by clicking the "tick" mark.

Comment: And in the first post, you do not mentioned about display function :)

Comment: @muhammedoğuz True, but they reacted to my nagging about that... So, what is your point? (I assume that you did not un-upvote because of that...)

Answer (score 1):

temp != NULL condition should be ahead of temp->data != num inside while loop.
Because if the temp reaches to the end of list without any match then temp will be NULL and you can't have check value(temp->data != num) for NULL pointer.

Comment: I agree, but for a good answer you should explain why and the (potential) negative effects if not. Especially how it can cause the misbehaviour described in the question.

Comment: How does your (valid) observation answer the question? Can you explain how this causes an infinite loop?

Comment: Thank you i fixed it but it's not the problem