# Trying to sort a linked list

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

There are many implementations available on the net, but I wanted to do it on my own.

Can anyone tell what mistakes I am making?

When I created the linked list, I gave input as 3,12,5,2. So after sorting it should have been 2,3,5,12, but it gave me output as 3,5,2,12.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;      
};
struct node *start=NULL;

void sort()
{
    struct node *preptr, *ptr, *temp;
    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr=start;
    while(ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        preptr=ptr;
        ptr=ptr->next;
        if (preptr->data > ptr->data )
        {
            temp->data=ptr->data;
            ptr->data=preptr->data;
            preptr->data=temp->data;
            ptr=start;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I run your code it gives the correct output.

Comment: Please make a [mre] to demonstrate what you describe.

Comment: Please confirm that you want to sort the values in the sorted list and not the nodes. That is very unusual.

Comment: @G.Sliepen what output did you give?

Comment: @Yunnosch i want to sort the entire node

Comment: Then you should manipulate pointers, not the values they are pointing to. I.e. you need to strictly avoid this code fragment, which currently occurs several times in your code `->data=`.

Comment: Have a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858

Comment: @Yunnosch so i should do `->next` instead of `->data`

Comment: Yes, if you manage that you have changed from value manipulatoin to pointer manipulation. But that is of course more than doing a text replace....

Comment: "what output did you give?" is the wrong question. You should ask "How is this tested?". And the one to answer that question is you. Please provide a [mre] (with hard-coded input and with a report of the output) to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have attempted to implement Bubble Sort, but that requires multiple passes through the data in the general, and you perform only one.  On that one pass, with input 3, 12, 5, 2, your code

1. compares 3 with 12, and makes no change;
2. compares 12 with 5, and swaps them;
3. compares 12 with 2, and swaps them.

Then it stops, leaving 3, 5, 2, 12 as the final result.

A Bubble Sort on an *n*-element list must make *n* - 1 passes through the list in the general case, and your particular input happens to require that maximum number of passes.  One way to fix it would be to just run your existing code for one sorting pass inside a `for` loop that runs *n* - 1 times, but of course you then need to compute *n* first.  A better way (without changing to an altogether better algorithm) would be to run an indeterminate number of passes, via an outer loop, keeping track of whether any swaps are performed during the pass.  You're then done when you complete a pass without making any swaps.

Additional notes:

- You don't need a `struct node` just to swap the `int` data of two nodes.
- If want a `struct node` for a local temporary, you don't need to allocate it dynamically.  Just declare it:

  ```
   struct node temp_node;
  ```
- If you want a `struct node *` for a local temporary, you (probably) do not need to allocate any memory for it to point to.
- If you want a `struct node` for a local temporary *and* a pointer to it, you *still* don't need to allocate anything dynamically.  Just declare the struct and take its address:

  ```
   struct node temp_node;
   struct node *temp = &temp_node;
  ```

  The main reasons to allocate dynamically are that you don't know in advance how much memory you will need, or that the allocated object needs to outlive the execution of the function in which it is created.
- Sorting a linked list is usually accomplished by rearranging the nodes by changing their links, not by swapping the node payloads, as your function does.  It's not necessarily *wrong* to swap the payloads, but that does not take any advantage of the linked list structure.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in comments that you actually need to move the nodes, not the values, you will need to reassign the `next` pointers.

For the same reason, it must be possible for `start` to reference a different node. Therefore I would suggest that `sort` takes `start` as an argument and returns the new value it.

For implementing bubble sort, you need an extra outer loop, which restarts the iteration over the list. This should be repeated at most *n* times, where *n* is the number of nodes in your list. You could also just check whether a swap was necessary and in that case decide to do another scan through your list... until no more swaps occur.

I have here implemented that second idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;      
};

// A function to create a new node. 
// This allows for easy initialisation of a linked list
struct node *newNode(int data, struct node *next) {
    struct node *temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = next;
    return temp;
}

// Useful to see what is in the list...
void printList(struct node *cur) {
    while (cur != NULL) {
        printf("%i ", cur->data);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// Let the sort function
struct node * sort(struct node *start) {
    struct node *prev, *cur, *next;
    // flag indicating we are not sure yet that 
    //    the list is sorted
    int mutation = 1;
    // extra dummy node that precedes the start node
    struct node sentinel; 
    sentinel.next = start;

    while (mutation) {
        mutation = 0;
        prev = &sentinel;
        cur = sentinel.next;
        next = start->next;
        while (next != NULL) {
            if (cur->data > next->data ) {
                // swap cur and next
                prev->next = next;
                cur->next = next->next;
                next->next = cur;
                // flag that we need more iterations
                mutation = 1;
                // prepare for next iteration
                prev = next;
            } else {
                prev = cur;
                cur = next;
            }
            next = cur->next;
        }
    }
    return sentinel.next;
}

// demo:
int main(void) {
  // Create list that was given as example
  struct node *start = newNode(3, newNode(12, newNode(5, newNode(2, NULL))));

  printf("Input:\n");
  printList(start);
  start = sort(start);
  printf("Sorted:\n");
  printList(start);
  return 0;
}
```