# C program that creates a list of integers and prints them in ascending order

Tags: c

Hello I'm making a program about linked list that stores a list of integers and sorts them out in ascending order. I'm kinda stuck in the part were once I have input all the integers that need to be sorted, it only prints out the first integer. Can someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}; struct node *first;


void createLinkedList (int nodes){
    int nodeData, j;
    struct node *tail;
    struct node *current;
    
    
    first = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
    if (first == NULL){
        printf("There's an error allocating memory.");
    }
    else{
        printf("Input the elements in the linked list: \n");
        scanf("%d", &nodeData);
        
        first->data=nodeData;
        first->next=NULL;
        current=first;
        
        for (j=2; j<=nodes; j++){
            tail = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            
            if (tail == NULL){
                printf("There's an error allocating memory.");
                break;
            }
            else{
                scanf("&d", &nodeData);
                
                tail->data=nodeData;
                tail->next=NULL;
                current->next=tail;
                current=current->next;
            }
        }
    }   
}

void sortLinkedList (int nodes){
    int i, j, nodeDataCopy;
    struct node *current;
    struct node *nextNode;
    
    for (j=nodes-2; j>=0; j--){
        current=first;
        nextNode=current->next;
        
        for (i=0; i<=j; i++){
            
            if (current->data > nextNode->data){
                nodeDataCopy=current->data;
                current->data=nextNode->data;
                nextNode->data=nodeDataCopy;
            }
            
            current=nextNode;
            nextNode=nextNode->next;
        }
    }
}

void displayLinkedList(){

    struct node *current;
    
    current=first;
    
    while (current != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", current->data);
        current=current->next;  
    }
}

int main (){
    int nodes;
    
    first=NULL;
    
    printf("Input the number of elements in the linked list:\n ");
    scanf("%d", &nodes);
    
    createLinkedList (nodes);;
    sortLinkedList (nodes);
    
    printf("Sorted order:\n");
    displayLinkedList();
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Here's an image of the compiled output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiht2.png)

Comment: I think it's time for you to learn how to use a *debugger*. With a debugger you cn step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. I also recommend that you simultaneously draw your list on paper, using labeled boxes for the nodes and arrows for the links (or pointers in general). The erase and redraw the arrows as you step through the code, to simulate what the code is doing.

Comment: *shudder* Global variables...

Comment: Why did you post the output as a picture? Copy/paste it as text.

Comment: Pen and paper is a helpful tool: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858 Use it based on the assumption that if your output function only shows one node, then there is only one node in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple typo. change ampersand to percent:

from:

```
scanf("&d", &nodeData);
```

to:

```
scanf("%d", &nodeData);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm crying my butt here already T_T