# CS 50 Recover Segmentaiton Fault

Tags: c, cs50

Getting a segmentation fault while working on this problem. Appreciate any help anyone can give me. I'm not sure where I would be getting a segmentation fault looking at this code as I believe all the pointers are pointing to separate spots in memory.

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BLOCKSIZE 512
#define Filesize 8
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage ./recover image\n");
    return 1;
  }

  int counter = -1;
  BYTE buffer[BLOCKSIZE]; // creates a buffer with size BLOCKSIZE taking up
                          // memory of 8 bits
  char filename[8];
  FILE *inputFp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  FILE *outputFp = NULL;
  bool foundjpg = false;

  // fread(Ptr to where you store it to, size of the elements you read, number
  // of elements, where you read from)
  while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), BLOCKSIZE, inputFp) != 0) {
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff &&
        (buffer[3] & 0xe0) == 0xe0) {
      foundjpg = true;

      if (outputFp != NULL) {
        fclose(outputFp);
      }

      counter = counter + 1;

      sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
      outputFp = fopen(filename, "a");

      fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), BLOCKSIZE, outputFp);

      if (foundjpg == true) {
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), BLOCKSIZE, outputFp);
      }
    }

    fclose(inputFp);
    fclose(outputFp);

    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: please set language tag, c/c++?

Comment: Run your program in a debugger and single step until you hit the segmentation fault, then look at what could have caused it.

Comment: or Fill your program with debug prints and try to follow what it does. It will tell you where your problem is.

Comment: Helpful tactics in situations like this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858 they help avoiding the impression that you expect others to do the debugging for you. Because StackOverflow has people who happily help with that, but not do it for you...

Answer (score 1):

At least these problem:

**Close before open**

`fclose(outputFp)` should not get called unless `fopen()` occurred.  I suspect this is OP's seg fault.

**Reading a scant buffer**

`while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), BLOCKSIZE, inputFp) != 0)` only checks if a least one byte was read, yet later code assume `BLOCKSIZE` bytle read.

Recommend reading [File format structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure)

**Tiny buffer**

Below fails when `counter > 999`.

```
BYTE buffer[BLOCKSIZE]; // creates a buffer with size BLOCKSIZE taking up memory of 8 bits
sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
```

Use a buffer size adequate for all `int`.

```
#define Filesize (10 /* INT_MIN */ + 4 /* ".jpg" */ + 1 /* \0 */)
```

**Close before done**

Certainly `fclose(inputFp); fclose(outputFp); return 0;` mean to be outside the `while` loop.