# Segmentation fault while looping through a linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I'm just learning about linked lists and I tried to create a function, that loops through a linked list and prints out every value.

However, at the end of my while-loop, when I past the last node I got an segmentation fault.

I though I would get rid of the segmentation fault by setting the condtion from (temp != NULL) to (temp->next != NULL), but still I got the error.
I would appriciate some help here.

I provide the print function in which I get the error, but I also could provide the complete code if needed.

```
void printList(node_t *head){
    node_t *temp = head;

    if (temp != NULL) {
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            int i = temp->value;
            printf("%d\n", i);
            temp = temp->next;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Added some more code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node_t;

void printList(node_t *head){
    node_t *temp = head;

    if (temp != NULL) {
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            int i = temp->value;
            printf("%d\n", i);
            temp = temp->next;

        }
    }

}

node_t *create_new_node(int value){
    node_t *next_pointer = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    next_pointer->value = value;
    next_pointer->next = NULL;
    return next_pointer;
}

node_t *insert_at_head(node_t **head, node_t *new_node){
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
    return new_node;
}

int main(){
    node_t *tmp, *head;

    for(int i= 0; i<25; i++){
        tmp = create_new_node(i);
        insert_at_head(&head, tmp);
    }
    
    printList(head);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your logic can be simplified.  Remember that a while loop won't execute  if the condition is false.

Comment: @avvocato Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You mean because of the if-statment? I used it just in case the head is Empty.  Before that I used while( temp != null) to check the head too.

Comment: With that program logic, you'll miss the last element. But I don't see how this can segfault unless the creation of the list is bogous in the first place, typically the next pointer of the last element might point nowhere. That's a typical beginner's error. You need to [edit] and show us a [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Try initialising head.

Comment: Hint: where does `head`point the very first time you insert something?

Comment: @Yunnosch thx for the advice, I initialized *head to NULL at the beggining of the main and now it works, but I dont really get why.

Comment: @avvocato if you don't get why, take a piece of paper and draw the nodes and arrows that show where the next pointer points and simulate your code. Alternatively you could invest 30 minutes of your time and learn the basics of your debugger, which allows you to execute your program line by line and lets you inspect the contents of variables.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I like coat hangers for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858

Comment: @Jabberwocky , thx for the advice. I got why I didnt found the problem. I already used my debugger but at first  I didnt understood why the last Node ist pointing somwhere. I didnt thought about, that the first element I insert will get the pointer of head.

Comment: @Yunnosch IMO your coathangers are not very readable, I prefer a pencil and a piece of paper. This is just my personal opinion.

Comment: @Jabberwocky If you are routined, pen an pencil are better. To get the hang of it, by more easily/faster, changing pointers, I like hangers. Pen and pencil requires foresight and a good eraser. But I do not contradict you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise head:

```
node_t *tmp, *head=NULL;
```

That way what ends up being the very last `next` is well defined and will prevent access who-knows-where.

Then I get a nice backward output (minus the last element, first inserted, the 0; see comment by Jabberwocky).

E.g. here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

Otherwis you do:

head->OhNo
head->1->OhNo
head->2->1->OhNo
....

This will trip up your output function, when it arrvives at/before the "OhNo", which points who-knows-where.

With init it is
head->NULL
head->1->NULL
head->2->1->NULL
...

The latter works cleanly with your output function.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the `printList` misses the first element.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of the program is that you did not initialize the pointer to the head node

```
node_t *tmp, *head;
```

As a result as new nodes are added to the head the data member next of the last node has an indeterminate value.

You need to write

```
node_t *tmp, *head = NULL;
```

The function `printList` can look the following way

```
void printList( const node_t *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", head->value );
    }
}
```

Also the function `create_new_node` should be defined the following way

```
node_t * create_new_node( int value )
{
    node_t *next_pointer = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if ( next_pointer != NULL )
    {
        next_pointer->value = value;
        next_pointer->next = NULL;
    }

    return next_pointer;
}
```