# How to visualize the creation of Linked-List in memory

Tags: c, linked-list

I need clarification on the following C code which is used to create Linked-List in Heap memory using Dynamic Memory Allocation. The code creates a Linked-List by copying the elements of the array A. I am confused as to what values are stored in data or next as we progress downwards.

```
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        struct Node *next;
    }*First = NULL;

    int A[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 10};

    int main()
    {
        struct Node *t, *last;
        First = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        First->data = A[0];
        First->next = NULL;
        Last = First;

        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            t = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            t->data=A[i];
            t->next=NULL;
            Last->next=t;
            Last=t;
        }
    }
```

Now, I am trying to visualize how `First` is created in the memory. Since Node contains two sections, data and next, when First pointer is initialized to NULL as in this statement `*First = NULL`, where is the 0 stored? Both of the sections? i.e.

```
    First->data = 0;
    First->next = 0;
```

As we continue downwards, we find the line `Last = First`, meaning `Last->data` contains 2 &
`Last->next` contains 0? i.e.

```
    Last->data = First->data;
    Last->next = First->next;
```

In the for loop, the statement `Last->next=t` is the most confusing. Does `t->data` holds 3 during the first iteration of the loop & `t->next` holds NULL. What exactly does this statement do?

Thank you.

Comment: `t` is a pointer variable. `Last->next` is (morally) a pointer variable. `Last->next = t` just assigns the value of `t` to `Last->next`, just like any other assignment statement. Do you know what pointers are?

Comment: The best thing you can do here is taking a piece of paper and a pencil. Draw the allocated structs as a rectangle and represent the next pointer with an arrow from pointing to the corrresponding rectangle, like e.g. [here](https://prepinsta.com/c-program/singly-linked-list/). There are hundreds of examples, tutorials, examples etc all over the internet and also probably in your C text book.

Comment: t is a pointer meaning, the memory location of t->data is stored in Last->next? Is that what you meant?

Comment: Try to learn the terminology.  What you're calling "sections" are structure "fields", or structure "members".  Each instance of a structure contains those two fields.  The `First` pointer is initially `NULL`.  At the start of `main`, it is changed to point to the first structure.  Also, I don't see where `n` is defined, but presumably it's the number of elements in the array.  Note that this code will fail if `n` is zero, which I would call a bug.  List implementations should always handle the empty list.

Comment: Initially, `First->data` and `First->next` do not exist because `First` is `NULL`. A null pointer value does not point to anything, so a null pointer value is a good choice of value to mark the end of a list.

Comment: "t is a pointer meaning, the memory location of t->data is stored in Last->next?". Really, the memory location (i.e. the "address") of `*t` is stored in `Last->next`. `*t` is a `struct Node` and its address can be written `&*t` and is a `struct Node *`. The `&*` part cancels out, so `&*t` has the same value as `t` (but `t` is also an *lvalue* meaning it can be used as the left operand of an assignment operator, whereas `&*t` is not an *lvalue*).

Comment: Most algorithm books have visualization of linked lists - without one, the concept is pretty hard to teach. Also, unrelated, creating a linked list with individual allocation of nodes is not a great idea on modern computers. You can copy/shuffle around a plain array in _much_ faster time than the slowly grinding wheels of malloc. Plus the access time turns bad as well.

Comment: In my comment above, `*t` is an expression meaning the object pointed to by `t`. This is not to be confused with `struct Node *t;` which is a *declaration* of `t` as a `struct Node *`.

Comment: If you are asking for methods/tricks/tools to visualise pointer constructs like linked lists, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C37.8967#59097858 (admittedly one of my answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I am trying to visualize how First is created in the memory. Since Node contains two sections, data and next, when First pointer is initialized to NULL as in this statement `*First = NULL`, where is the 0 stored?

There is no such *statement* in your code, for at least two reasons:

1. that snippet is excerpted from a *declaration* (of variable `First`), not from any statement.  This is relevant in part because
2. excerpting it from its larger context obscures its meaning.  If it were a complete assignment statement then it would express an (invalid) assignment to a structure object of type `struct Node` designated by the expression `*First`, but as it actually stands, the `= NULL` is an initializer for the object designated by variable `First`, a pointer of type `struct Node *`.

The pointer object designated by `First` is completely different from the structure object, if any, to which its pointer value points.  It is crucial to understand differences such as this, between pointers and the objects to which they point.

So, "where is the 0 stored"?  In the sense you mean, **nowhere**.  No `struct Node` has been declared at that point.  There is neither a `First->data` nor a `First->next` at that point.  Initializing `First` to `NULL` expressly ensures that.

> As we continue downwards, we find the line `Last = First`, meaning `Last->data` contains 2 & `Last->next` contains 0?

Yes and no.  `Last` is another pointer of type `struct Node *`, again distinct from the object to which it points.  `Last = First` is a *pointer* assignment, immediately after which, `Last` points to the same object, if any, that `First` does, which at that point is a recently mallocated object.  No members of such an object are accessed or set to achieve that, but as a result, `Last->data` does evaluate to 2, and `Last->next` to a null pointer.  And note well that a null pointer is not the same thing as the integer 0.

> In the for loop, the statement `Last->next=t` is the most confusing.

It is completely analogous to the `Last = First` statement you asked about previously.  *Pointer* `Last` is assigned to point to the same object to which *pointer* `t` points, which is again a recently mallocated object.  On the `i == 1` iteration of the loop, `t->data` will have just been set to `A[1]`, which is 3.

Perhaps **an analogy** will help drive home the key distinctions here.

- Suppose I give you a card on which the street address of my house is printed. Do you then hold my house itself in your hand?  No, of course not, but you could use the information on the card to go to my house to take a photo of it or make a delivery.
- If you make a copy of the card and give it to a friend, then have you changed anything about my house?  Or are there now two houses where once there was one?  Of course not.  There are now two *cards* both describing how to find the same house.
- If your friend uses the information on their card to go to my house and paint it, then does the color of either card change?  No.  The cards are not the house itself.  But if you afterward use the information on your card to go to my house then will you see its new color?  Yes, you will, because the information on your card leads you to the same house.
- If someone gives you another card with an address on it, how can you tell whether is refers to the same house?  Easy: you need only compare the information printed on the card.  In particular, you don't need to go to the address printed on either card.
- If you burn your card, is my house damaged?  Can your friend still find it using their copy of the card?  Can *you* still find it if you happen to remember the address that was printed on it?  No, yes, and yes.
- If you white-out the address printed on your card, so that it is blank, does the information on it still tell you how to locate my house?  Or *any* house?  No.

My house represents an object of interest, such as a `struct Node`.  It has parts such as doors, windows, and walls that can be examined or manipulated, somewhat like the members of a structure.

The cards represent pointer objects.  In our analogy, they are all one part, which can be manipulated to record the address of a house.

The data *on* the cards represent pointer values, which happen to be called "addresses" in C terminology, too.

Addresses are each a uniquely identifying characteristic of a particular house / object.  Addresses can be recorded on cards / in pointer objects, which are completely different things than the houses or objects the addresses on them identify.  Multiple cards / pointer objects or none can contain the address of the same house / object.  The fact that there is a card / pointer object does not imply that whatever is printed on it, if anything, is the address of a house / object that actually exists.